# MySQL return list of ids matching multiple rows

Tags: mysql, database, search, join

I've got following table schema and values:

[image: Table structure and values]

What i want to achieve is to get the list of the provider ids (id_provider) which match multiple criterias, for example:

- I want to search by id_attribute = 71 and the value 3400 and also want to filter that table by id_attribute = 70 which value is 4300. Return provider list should be: (2)
- Next search - id_attribute = 72 and the filtered value is between 200 and 700, so it should return provider list equal to (2,3).

Is this possible with that kind of structure?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What query have you written so far?

Comment: I tried using GROUP BY id_provider and HAVING clause but didn't get what I expected..

Comment: Your desired results are very difficult to comprehend based on the question and the comments below. I suggest you find a way to re-phrase that may shed more clarity on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are combining values from different rows, so think `group by` and `having`.  Your first query is:

```
select id_provider
from
group by id_provider
having max(id_attribute = 71 and value = '3400') > 0 and
       max(id_attribute = 70 and value = '4300') > 0;
```

And the second:

```
select id_provider
from
group by id_provider
having max(id_attribute = 72 and value between '200' and '700') > 0;
```

Note the quotes are because the value column is really a string.  If you need numeric comparisons, you may need to convert to numbers.

Comment: Perfect, that works the way I wanted. Thank you very much for that answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your first query, your where clause would be like `... WHERE (id_attribute = 71 AND value = "3400") AND (id_attribute = 70 AND value = "4300");`

In your second one, you would have to use BETWEEN `... WHERE id_attribute = 72 AND value BETWEEN(200,700);`

You also might have to use `SELECT DISTINCT id_provider` so you don't end up with multiple identical ids.

Comment: Not exactly, for the first one you search only for one attribute, I want to filter using two attributes (71 and 70) at the same time (or even more attributes).

Comment: Sorry I read too fast and I skipped one line, sounds like you would have to use `OR`

Comment: But if I use OR I will get the result even if only one criteria is matched. If I use AND none of the result will be returned.

Comment: Not if you use then with the brackets; both condition inside the bracket would have to be true in order to return true (with an `AND`). Take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Comment: I know that both of them should be true, but when I try to search for two attrubutes and values the result is null. Only when I use OR it works, but the result is not okay cause it returns the provider id even if only one of the criterias is matched, not both of them.

Comment: Like Naren said in it's answer, the value field look like it's a varchar. you might have to add quotes around the value you're searching: `... WHERE (id_attribute = 71 AND value = "3400") OR (id_attribute = 70 AND value = "4300");`

Comment: It's not the point I think. That kind of query works, it returns provider ids but look, with this query `... WHERE (id_attribute = 71 AND value = "3400") OR (id_attribute = 70 AND value = "4300");` I will get the proper ID, with this `... WHERE (id_attribute = 71 AND value = "3400") OR (id_attribute = 70 AND value = "4600");` I will also receive the same ID but I don't want to, I want both criteria matched to return provider ID.

Comment: Oh, you only have to change the `OR` for and `AND` then: `... WHERE (id_attribute = 71 AND value = "3400") AND (id_attribute = 70 AND value = "4300");`

Comment: I've created sql fiddle for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd86d/2
When I use AND between two conditions nothing was returned..

Comment: ok I understand your point... I'll have to let this simmer a bit, I dont see how to do this in a clean way at the moment (without nested queries)...

Answer (score 0):

first search:

```
SELECT your_fields
FROM your_table
WHERE ((id_attribute = 71 AND value = 3400) AND (id_attribute = 70 AND value=4300))
```

Second search:

```
SELECT your_fields
FROM your_table
WHERE (id_attribute = 72 AND (value BETWEEN 200 AND 700) )
```

I've used many brackets to let you see the "logical" subdivision.

Comment: The first search doesn't work, tried that already but I think it's not so simple. I can't for two id_attributes in single WHERE clause I think.

Answer (score 0):

other answers are correct bt kamil your value field is look like varchar....u can not use "between" for varchar.

u can use it only for range ...i.e. between some date or between numbers.